# Filling in Specific Empty Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to fill in cells that are missing data in Column B with a placeholder (ie. 0) so they don't get deleted by my other macro. I'm hoping for some VBA code that will emulate the following formula and apply it to all of the rows:

=IF(B2="",IF(COUNT(C2:I2)>0,0,""),"")

I want the result of this formula to go into Column B (cell B2 in the example above). The purpose of this formula is to only put the placeholder value in Column B if at least one of the cells in Columns C:I has a number.

Any help/refinements are much appreciated!

Edit: What I've tried to add to the macro

```
Sub test()
Dim nRows As Integer: nRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cell As Range, r As Range: Set r = Range("A2:A" & nRows)
Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = Range("B2:B" & nRows)
Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = Range("I2:I" & nRows)

For Each cell In r2
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        For Each cell In r1
            If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = 0
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: `I'm hoping for some VBA code` - what you tried yourself? Show us the code you are trying and where it may not be working, then we can help you solve it. SO is not a code writing website.

Comment: This is the code I have currently based on searches on this website but I'm still pretty new to VBA and don't quite know how to translate that formula above to fit in here:

Edit:too long to paste here, see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will update column B (ActiveSheet.UsedRange) if at least one cell in columns C:I has a number

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setPlaceholderInColB()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B2").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(C2:I2)>0,0,"""")"
        .Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks Paul. I always get mixed up trying to define ranges.